# how to use the keyword `VALUES` in an `IN` statement?

Tags: sql-server, query, select, insert, syntax

I am on sql server 2016

```
select @@version
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU15) (KB4577775) - 13.0.5850.14 (X64)
> Sep 17 2020 22:12:45    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
> Enterprise Edition:  Core-based Licensing (64-bit)  on Windows Server
> 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Inside a simple insert statement in sql server I have the key word `values`

for example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT

INSERT INTO [APCore].[usr].[userBusinessArea]
           ([businessAreaID]
           ,[userID])
     VALUES
           (21, 368), 
           (21, 227419) ,
           (21, 99906), 
           (21, 140470)


SELECT [1]= @@TRANCOUNT
--COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
--ROLLBACK
SELECT [2]=@@TRANCOUNT
```

The problem is that before I run the insert I would like to use the same logic with the `values` in order to find out if any of these records is already in the table.

otherwise you might end up with this:

[image]

the way I have done is:

```
select top 10 * from
[APCore].[usr].[userBusinessArea]
where businessAreaid = 21
 and Userid in
(368,227419,99906,140470)
```

this is `after` the insert:

[image]

I saw some examples in here: [SQL Server IN Operator](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-in/)

Is there a *good* and *worth* way to use `values` in an `in` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to reference the `VALUES` clause just as you would if it were materialised.

```sql
INSERT INTO [APCore].[usr].[userBusinessArea]
           ([businessAreaID]
           ,[userID])
SELECT 
    businessAreaID,
    userID
FROM (
     VALUES
           (21, 368), 
           (21, 227419) ,
           (21, 99906), 
           (21, 140470)
) v (businessAreaID, userID)
WHERE v.userID NOT IN (368,227419,99906,140470);
```

See also [the examples in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause)

[Try it on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f044caf04a95af57b7e860e796b6777)

Comment: Thank you for the code, the docs reference, and for the fiddle, I thought it was a silly question at first, I am glad I posted as this is going to help me a lot, including in the automating scripts I like to produce.

Comment: Merge could do this as well without the need for the NOT IN usage.